# Honestly, why is my question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[What is the “/” in the addresses in Scotland stand for?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/what-is-the-in-the-addresses-in-scotland-stand-for)

I am not annoyed or anything but the decision seems wrong (to me at least)

- My mom just moved to Scotland from a third world country and she is trying to settle which makes this question perfect for this site "a question about the postal system from a person trying to settle abroad"
- As far as I can tell the question received no down votes.
- The decision has not been made by the community (fiver users) as usual.
- A good answer is there, also received no down votes.

I still think Mark Mayo rocks :)

Comment: ->  [Expatriates sucks because most questions are about Immigration](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/284/164)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it's a tricky edge case.  It's something that you need to learn as an expat, sure, but it's also a question that equally affects locals and expats - anyone who lives in Scotland has to work it out.

In the absence of a moderator, 5 users can close it, but someone can always flag it for us to look at and close if it doesn't meet the terms as an expat.

We're having to be really strict in beta, so if it's not a problem exclusive to expats (ie not a problem for locals too) then it's considered off topic.  Some of the questions here work on travel.stackexchange.com, but yeah, if it's not a problem only for expats, it's not for here.

Thanks, I'm glad you think I rock :)

Comment: I am not sure the community agrees with yiur distinction. There is some discussion about this in http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/42/can-questions-that-would-apply-equally-to-locals-be-on-topic.

Comment: @StrongBadI'm fairly sure that distinction is (as the answer there says) where it applies *more* to expats.  How addresses work in Scotland? I'm not so sure that applies. I could be wrong.